# Add class to last section of an article

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i want is to add a class to the last section of the article with "class2". Would be very nice if you could help me out for this problem.
Thanks for your time and the answers. Sorry for my bad english.

```
<article class="class1">
    <section>
        <p>...</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p>something</p>
    </section>
</article>
<article class="class2">
    <section>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p>add class to this section</p>
    </section>
</article>
```

Comment: `$('.class2 section:last').addClass("class");`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.class2 section:last').addClass("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

use `:last`

```
$('.class2 section:last').addClass("custom-class");
```

Answer (score -1):

Using only Js

```
var sections = document.querySelectorAll("article.class2 section"); // This way you get an array with all the <section> in your article.class2
sections[sections.length-1].className="class"; //with the first part you take the last element of the array and then you apply the class you want
```